# get_template_directory_uri() not working

Tags: customization, get-template-part

I am getting trouble with the following lines of code. Actually I have created  a ***custom file*** `confirm_email.php` in which I wrote the following piece of code. When I'm ***removing*** `$temp_dir variable` it works fine, but when I include it, this page returns ***internal server error***

```
$temp_dir   = get_template_directory_uri();

$url        = $temp_dir."/confirm_email.php?id=".$_REQUEST['id']."&key=".$_REQUEST['key'];
$message    = "Username:".$_REQUEST['name']."Click on below link to confirm your email;".$url;

$subject    = "Email confirmation Link";
$headers    = "From: wordpress@property-penang.com" . "\r\n";

if ( mail( $_REQUEST['email'], $subject, $message, $headers ) ) {
    echo "1";
} else {
    echo "0";
}
```

Comment: Where and how is $url used later?

Comment: i will send it to email

Comment: No, the code. Show the code. That's where the issue will be.

Comment: i updated the above code

Comment: This script looks exploitable, with no validation/sanitazion. Also you don't want external evil bots calling this script 1000 times a minute.

Comment: Right . i will do it in functions.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the problem, Your `confirm_email.php` function should be inside the scope of wordpress. If you include the file into `functions.php` file or some file that is inside the wp scope then `get_template_directory_uri()` function will work.

You can get around the problem by adding the code into a filter or action hook instead of a file. You can try `init` hook. you can add some parameter in the url to check like `http://your_domain.com/?is_email=true` and then check it in the code like this:

```
if($_GET['is_email'] == true){
    // do your stuffs
}
```

Your solution code might be something like this:

```
function my_email_function(){
    if(isset($_GET['is_email']) && $_GET['is_email'] == true){
        $temp_dir   = get_template_directory_uri();

        $url        = $temp_dir."/confirm_email.php?id=".$_REQUEST['id']."&key=".$_REQUEST['key'];
        $message    = "Username:".$_REQUEST['name']."Click on below link to confirm your email;".$url;

        $subject    = "Email confirmation Link";
        $headers    = "From: wordpress@property-penang.com" . "\r\n";

        if ( mail( $_REQUEST['email'], $subject, $message, $headers ) ) {
            echo "1";
        } else {
            echo "0";
        }
    }
}
add_action('init', 'my_email_function');
```

Comment: Not working. giving same result

Comment: Now try this solution. :)

Comment: this is working